# Using Mockito for HTTP Client

Tags: java, json, mocking, mockito

I have a stubbed JSON OBJECT but need to mock the following using Mockito:

```
HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(postRequest);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);        
}
JSONObject jsonResponseObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
```

I have created the following Mocks:

```
@Mock
    private HttpClient mockHttpClient;
    private HttpPost mockHttpPost;
    private HttpResponse mockHttpResponse;
    private HttpEntity mockHttpEntity; 
    private InputStream mockInputStream;
    private InputStreamReader mockInputStreamReader;
    private BufferedReader mockBufferedReader;
```

And have the following `when` statements:

```
    Mockito.when(mockHttpClient.execute(mockHttpPost)).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse); 
    Mockito.when(mockHttpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(mockHttpEntity);
    Mockito.when(mockHttpEntity.getContent()).thenReturn(mockInputStream);
```

Question: Do I need to create all these 'when' statements and if yes then which other ones do I need to create to be able to get to the stubbed JSON?

Any suggestions pls?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some more code so we can understand exact mocking objects

Comment: Are you using any web frameworks like Spring MVC?

Answer (score 6):

You *might* have to mock `HttpClient` and `HttpResponse`, if they're interfaces (although, depending on your library, you could use `MockHttpClient` or `MockHttpResponse`), but you *shouldn't* be mocking anything else.

Why?

The mock is establishing expected output behavior on classes that we cannot make concrete, or rather, classes that we want to behave in a certain way for this particular instance of a test.  You want to ensure that you get the correct response back from a mock `HttpClient`, and that when `response.getEntity()` is called, that it gives back a meaningful `HttpEntity`.  You can elect to mock that out or not; I personally wouldn't, as the mock doesn't add any extra value (except to perhaps verify that a particular method was called).

Everything else is a concrete implementation - you should be allowing the other objects to interact with the results of the previously mocked elements to ensure that they behave as they would if there were no mocks.

Actually...you really can't mock those unless you pass them in or inject them in some way.  I would ***strongly*** discourage you from attempting to mock any `new`ed objects in that method.

You don't specify what you're asserting, but I would expect that it's your `JSONObject` in some capacity.  I'd assert that what you expected to be placed into it actually made it into the JSON object, and also verify that your mocked objects were called and invoked in the way you expected them to be.

Your annotation `@Mock` is not cascading, by the way - you have to annotate all mocked fields with `@Mock`, then either annotate the test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)`, or use `MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this)` (one or the other; both aren't required except under edge cases).  If you choose the annotations, don't forget `@InjectMocks` on your test object.

Lastly, your `when` conditions do what I would expect them to do - those should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you might need all the when statements that you've mentioned.
But instead of returning the `mockInputStream`, you could just return `new ByteArrayInputStream( "{foo : 'bar'}".getBytes() )`

Finally, you could verify that the json response object has a 'foo' property that has a value 'bar'.

That said, I'm not sure whether the given method is worth testing - since all it does it open streams and read data.

Answer (score 0):

First understand meaning of `Mocking`.

1)Why we need mocking?

Suppose we don't want to call any original method and want that instead of that original method we should call a dummy method then we should go for mocking.

For e.g:

```
Mockito.when(mockHttpClient.execute(mockHttpPost)).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse)
```

This means whenever this `execute()` will be called then you will return your own prepared value instead of original `mockHttpResponse`.

So in your case prepare your stub object and mockit if you need that.
Here you prepare your response(Note actual but dummy).

```
mockHttpResponse.setEntity(new Entity());
mockHttpResponse.getEntity().setContent('{yourJsonString}');
```

So whenever your

```
  mockHttpClient.execute(mockHttpPost); //will be called
```

Then it will return the response that you prepared in your test method manually.

When your control comes to

```
  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Then you will get `{yourJsonString}` when `response.getEntity().getContent()` is called and let  rest code do its functionality. At end your JSON stubbed object will be prepared.

Remember test cases are just for developers help.We can mock anything and return anything or any stub object.Just we write test case to check our control flow by passing expected and non expected values.

This will make your work easy.Now you want to mock your BufferReader class use this.

```
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(BufferedReader.class); 
 when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("first line").thenReturn("second line");

 org.junit.Assert.when(new Client(bufferedReader).parseLine()).thenEquals(IsEqual.equalTo("1"));
```

Comment: Hi Shoaib, Thanks for the clarification!! Not sure what needs to be done here but I'm trying to avoid making an actual HttpClient call as I have the  final processed(Parsed) version of the response from this call, which is a JSON object that I have stubbed. Please advise.. Thanks

Comment: This is very helpful. But as I mentioned above in my question, I return a mockHttpResponse when HttpResponse response = defaultHttpClient.execute(postRequest) is called. But then in the actual method, I have to perform 3 steps before the JSON object is returned. So, if I were to return the stubbed JSON object when response.getEntity().getContent() is run, will that not be an issue when later statements in my original method are run? Please advise..

Comment: Follow this Link for more detail.I just explain you want to mock and when to mock rest depends on your perpective. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626609/mocking-httpclient-execute-issues-mockito